# Unable to deploy Ionic 4 app to iOS device

Tags: ios, xcode, typescript, cordova, ionic4

So far I've followed all of the online tutorials to deploy an Ionic 4 app to an iOS device.  I went through the code signing process and used the latest version of xCode to attempt to deploy my app to an iOS device.  According to xCode the deployment succeeds successfully, the icon appears on the device but when attempting to open and run it there's just a blank screen...the app never opens even though xCode displays a successful deployment.  I can deploy to Android successfully and run the app but not with iOS.  I'm not getting any errors, it just opens to a blank screen.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried running Ionic Cordova build iOS -prod —release? If so, is it successful?

Comment: Yes.  Actually ionic cordova build ios.  I didn't include the -prod --release tags.

Comment: Try it with those

Comment: No luck...still just opens up to blank screen on an ios device.

Tried the above suggestion as well as the following:
sudo ionic cordova build ios - --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
sudo ionic cordova prepare ios

Comment: Try removing the ios platform and re adding the platform. Also, make sure your app id is correct in the config.xml file